# Feathers - Unknown column in where clause when PATCH

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am using Sequelize for the mysql database.

When I use `Find` function by Postman, it returns:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "latestNewsId": "f8b53a32-b729-41f8-9888-df2b71e91177"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I tried to modify the `latestNewsId` in Postman using `Patch`, by `id`.

```
PATCH localhost:3030/latest_news_featured/1

Body:
{
     "latestNewsId": "f8b53a32-b729-41f8-9888-df2b71e12345"
}
```

This is the error occuring then:

```
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "Unknown column 'latest_news_featured.undefined' in 'where clause'",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "errors": {}
}
```

I don't know why would this happens because I checked and confirm `id` and `latestNewsId` exist in database.

latest_news_featured.models.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const latestNewsFeatured = sequelizeClient.define('latest_news_featured', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    latestNewsId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  latestNewsFeatured.associate = function (models) { };
  return latestNewsFeatured;
};
```

Comment: show your update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `latest-news-featured.class`, when I comment `this.options = options || {};`, it works instantly.

I am not sure the reason, so I leave this here and hope it can help others with the same problem.

latest-news-featured.class.js

```
const { Service } = require('feathers-sequelize');

exports.LatestNewsFeatured = class LatestNewsFeatured extends Service {
  
    constructor (options,app) {
        super(options, app);
        this.app = app;
        //this.options = options || {};   //Comment this line to make it works
    }
    ...

    ...
};
```